# android - Firestore get item position in order by query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firebase we can get by order as

```
citiesRef.orderBy("state").orderBy("population", Direction.DESCENDING);
```

I am wondering, Is it possible to get item position in ordered list without actual downloading whole data

Ex: If I asks what is the position of Las Vegas if ordered by population

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't allow you to do that from the server. You have to do it from your coding side, which means you need to download the whole data and sort it.

Documentation can be seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limitToLast)